# Saving a list using Codable or userDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftui, userdefaults

Can someone help me to save the list in this code using Codable or another methods. I am not able to use the UserDefaults in the code. Can anyone help me how to use save the lists so that when ever, I re-open my app, the list is still there.  Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI
struct MainView: View {

    @State var br = Double()
    @State var loadpay = Double()
    @State var gp : Double = 0
    @State var count: Int = 1
    @State var listcheck = Bool()
    @StateObject var taskStore = TaskStore()
 @State var name = String()
    var userCasual = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userCasual") as? String ?? ""
    func addNewToDo() {
         taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem:  "load \(count)", amount: Double(gp)))
   }
    func stepcount() {
       
     count += 1
        
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            HStack {
            Button(action: { gp += loadpay }) {
                Text("Add Load")
            }
            Button(action: {
                addNewToDo()
            }) {
                Text("Check")
            }
        }
            Form {
                ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) {
                    task in
                    Text(task.toDoItem)
                }
            }
        }
        Button(action: {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(name, forKey: "userCasual")})
        {Text("Save")}

}

}
struct Task : Identifiable {
    var id = String()
    var toDoItem = String()
    var amount : Double = 0
}

class TaskStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
}
```

Comment: Just a note, UserDefaults is the most insecure storage. It should only be used for its intended purpose of customizing behavior or maintaining preferences. Using it as a "Store" is not a good practice https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Task` adopt `Codable`

```
struct Task : Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = ""
    var toDoItem = ""
    var amount = 0.0
}
```

In `TaskStore` add two methods to *load* and *save* the tasks and an `init` method

```
class TaskStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "tasks"),
              let savedTasks = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Task].self, from: data) else { tasks = []; return }
        tasks = savedTasks
    }
    
    func save() {
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(tasks)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "tasks")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the view call `taskStore.save()` to save the data.

However: For large data sets `UserDefaults` is the wrong place. Save the data in the Documents folder or use Core Data.

Side note: Never use `value(forKey:)` in `UserDefaults`, in your example there is `string(forKey:)`

Comment: can you also please tell me how do I clear this task if I happen to add a clear button? Is it possible to clear/delete/refresh the task using just a clear button?

Comment: I mean clearing the whole task list. Not a particular task.

Comment: In `TaskStore ` add a function `func clear() { tasks.removeAll(); save() }`

Comment: and how do I call this function on a button? just clear() ?? Because that didn't work for me when I tried to call the function clear() in my Reset button. It says Cannot find tasks in scope.

Comment: As `save` you have to call it on `taskStore`: `taskStore.clear()`

Comment: It works, however, to check if  the list is cleared, you have to re-open the app. Can we clear the list while the user is still on the view ? Like getting a blank list when the user taps the clear button?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Its working now.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the @AppStorage property wrapper. Here is a [great article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper) written by Paul Hudson who is a great resource when you're learning iOS.

UserDefaults isn't the best way to store persistent information though. Once you get a bit more comfortable with Swift and SwiftUI, you should look into CoreData for storing your data across sessions.

Comment: @vadian's answer is excellent for what you are trying to do. However, in the long term I would not recommend it. AppStorage will work better with SwiftUI and seamlesly adding/removing elements, as will CoreData.

Comment: However, the App storage is only used for storing small values and can't be used on saving list, isn't?

Comment: This will not work for custom objects.